# Transform date formats

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in an Oracle table which is varchar and it contains different date formats like ‘dd-mom-yyyy’, ‘dd-mm-yyyy’, ‘dd/mm/yy’.
I need to transform all these formats into a single one, keeping the column as varchar.

Comment: This very vague question doesn't make any sense as it currently stands. If you have dates, store them in a date column, not in a varchar column. Generally, you should put more effort in your question pointing out what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Do you have 3 known formats or any arbitrary format? Because the latter is pretty much unsolvable (is 5/10/2023 5th October or 10th May?).

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `TO_DATE` with the `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` option to convert the string to a date against a known format and `TO_CHAR` to convert it back to a string and use `COALESCE` to check multiple formats:

```sql
UPDATE table_name
SET date_column = COALESCE(
                    TO_CHAR(
                      COALESCE(
                        TO_DATE(date_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'fxDD-MM-RR'),
                        TO_DATE(date_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'),
                        TO_DATE(date_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        TO_DATE(date_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
                      ),
                      'YYYY-MM-DD'
                    ),
                    date_column
                  )
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_column) AS
  SELECT '2023-01-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '01-25-2023' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '25-01-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '25-Jan-2023' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wed 25th January 2023' FROM DUAL
```

After the update, the table contains:

| DATE_COLUMN |
| --- |
| 2023-01-25 |
| 2023-01-25 |
| 2023-01-25 |
| 2023-01-25 |
| Wed 25th January 2023 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pdOwUwpY)

*Note: This normalises all the date formats that are tested in the `UPDATE` statement and will leave the non-matching formats as they were (so you will not lose data).*

---

Even better would be to store the values as a `DATE` data type and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, idea of storing dates as strings is bad. It always is.

You said you want to keep values as they are; it means that you'd actually just want to *display* values as valid dates. To do that, one option is to create your own function which accepts various values, tries to convert them to date and return it (if it succeeds).

You'd add other formats into the function, once you find them.

For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_format (par_datum in varchar2) return date is
  2  retval date;
  3  begin
  4    -- DD-MON-YYYY
  5    begin
  6      retval := to_date(par_datum, 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english');
  7    exception
  8      when others then
  9
 10        -- DD-MM-YYYY
 11        begin
 12          retval := to_date(par_datum, 'dd-mm-yyyy');
 13        exception
 14          when others then
 15
 16            -- DD/MM/YYYY
 17            begin
 18              retval := to_date(par_datum, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
 19            exception
 20              when others then
 21                null;
 22            end;
 23        end;
 24    end;
 25
 26    return retval;
 27  end;
 28  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it (setting date format, just to know *what is what*):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

`varchar2` column accepts even garbage; `45-19-2001` *looks like* date, but it is not.

```
SQL> select id, datum, f_format(datum) result
  2  from test
  3  order by id;

        ID DATUM                RESULT
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 25-OCT-1998          25.10.1998
         2 13-02-2022           13.02.2022
         3 03/11/1984           03.11.1984
         4 45-19-2001

SQL>
```